# Changing Done UIBarButtonItem's background image

Tags: iphone, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem

I want to make a custom UIBarButtonItem to represent the Done button.
I want to able to internationalize the app, so I want the text to be directly editable. To take into account different lengths of the "Done" Label, I've designed an stretchableImage. Is it possible to directly change the default edit button background or is a custom UIBarButtonItem needed? If so, what would be the way to dynamically resize the background stretchableImage according to the length of the label?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are targeting iOS 5.0 only, you can change the default appearance with the new `UIAppearance` methods, `-setBackButtonBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:` specifically.

If you need to support older versions of iOS, you should subclass `UIBarButtonItem`, add a `UIButton` instance variable, create it and call `–initWithCustomView:` in the `init` method of your `UIBarButtonItem`. That's because `UIBarButtonItem` is not a subclass of `UIView` and you can't draw your custom images in it. You should also set the `width` property of your `UIBarButtonItem` manually.

```
@interface MYCustomBarButtonItem : UIBarButtonItem
{
    UIButton *button;
}
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title; // name it in concordance with your needs
@end

#define kButtonHeight 30
#define kButtonTitleFontSize 12
#define kButtonTitlePadding 5

@implementation MYCustomBarButtonItem

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; // add retain here, and write the dealloc method if you aren't using ARC. Also, release it if self == nil.
    self = [super initWithCustomView:button];
    if (self) {
        UIFont *titleFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:kButtonTitleFontSize];
        CGSize titleSize = [title sizeWithFont:titleFont];
        CGFloat buttonWidth = titleSize.width + kButtonTitlePadding * 2;
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonWidth, kButtonHeight);
        self.width = buttonWidth;

        [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        // Set your styles
        button.titleLabel.font = titleFont;

        // Normal state background
        UIImage *backgroundImage = ...; // create your normal stretchable background image
        [button setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        // Pressed state background
        backgroundImage = ...; // create your pressed stretchable background image
        [button setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

        // and so on...
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

PS. Don't forget to override `target` and `action` properties of your subclass to work with your `button` instance.

Comment: How would do the resizing of the button depending on the text's width.  Also, how do you set the background as an stretchableImage? Thanks.

Comment: You use the `-sizeWithFont:` method of `NSString`: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html . The background is set with `UIButton`'s `-setBackgroundImage:forState:`.

Answer (score 2):

I might have misunderstood your question, but I believe all you want is this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"I am done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];
UIImage *stretchable = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"StretchableImage.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:16];
[btnDone setBackgroundImage:stretchable forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:btnDone];
```

A UIBarButtonItem does automatically adjust it's width to the width of the label.

Comment: @Stanislav Yaglo is right. This solution will only work with iOS 5. If you want to target older versions you will need to make a simple subclass of the UIBarButtonItem.